# Analisis de las curvas de carga electrica para optimizar la potencia contratada

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

En 2021 venimos sufriendo en España un incremento descontrolado de las tarifas eléctricas.

La gran mayoría de la gente no sabe 'destilar' los datos de su factura y tarifas para optimizarlos. Hay gente que si sabe, pero no se acaba de "decidir" a dar el salto y bajar la potencia contratada quizás porque no esta al 100% seguro de sus calculos o porque carece de referencias de otras personas que SI lo hayan hecho.

Para incrementar el consenso sobre lo que es un 'buen analisis y optimizacion' y sobre las opciones para hacer cambios es por lo que vengo a plantear estas preguntas:

- A) Como puedo saber la potencia electrica optima en funcion de mi consumo?
- B) Cuales son las opciones para cambiarla y sus costes?

PD: Yo suelo usar stackoverflow en Ingles y no he encontrado ningun otro web que permita discutir problemas de una forma mejor. Espero que no me cierren la pregunta porque de verdad considero que discutir este problema con la intencion de crear un 'auto-optimizador' (una simple hoja de calculo) podria ayudar a mucha gente.

Comment: Rub, bienvenido a S.O. en español.... desde ya, es necesario recomendarte que hagas un [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio y luego vayas a [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas... así tal como está esta te va llevar a puntuaciones negativas y reportes... la comunidad de Stackoverflow no resuelve tareas.

Answer (score 0):

A) Como puedo saber la potencia electrica optima en funcion de mi consumo?

Hay muchas webs que te piden datos para 'estimar' tu consumo.

Yo creo que mejor que estimar tu consumo es 'obtener los datos reales de consumo' los cuales puedes obtener de la distribuidora de tu zona y luego analizarlos.

Estos datos son 'por hora' pero el contador mide con una frecuencia mas alta, por lo que tendremos que hacer algunas estimaciones nosotros de 'peor caso'.

El estimador de la CNMC https://comparador.cnmc.gob.es/facturaluz/inicio/
te permite estimar costes en funcion de la potencia y consumo, pero no te ayuda a elegir una potencia adecuada a tu consumo (una que minimice la potencia contratada pero teniendo en cuenta los cortes de suministro que sufririas, sobre los datos).

Para ayudar en ese 'analisis de los datos' he creado esta hoja de calculo. Te animo a que hagas una 'copia privada' de la misma, introduzcas tus datos y juegues con la misma.

Si esto coge tracción (y no me cierran la pregunta), no me importa crear un video explicando para que es cada sección.

Aqui esta la hoja de calculo.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LMr-mB_EJXpWlESLLZI8J33zKRr8GnJKMujDX6RYlO4/edit?usp=sharing

Notas:

- Hay 2 estimaciones de 'cortes' la primera es muy de peor caso y la segunda es algo mas blanda y realista (0 cortes en mi caso).
- La segunda pestaña explica como se calculan esas 2 versiones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui la web de la que saque mucha informacion
https://nergiza.com/contadores-inteligentes-saltan-mas/

---

B) Cuales son las opciones para cambiarla y sus costes?

A dia de hoy (2021-07-25), si tienes tarifa 2TD tienes:

- 1 Bajada de potencia gratuita (1 para Pot-valle y 1 para Pot-picoYllano)
- 1 Subida de potencia gratuita (siempre que no sea por encima de la que tenias antes).

Al menos eso es lo que me han dicho en Regsiti*

`*` Si alguien quiere proporcionar links a esta informacion los anadire encantado.

Asi que si la bajas y te va mal, siempre puedes volver a donde estabas y NO te habras gastado nada por los cambios.